# Search between min and max in database from $_GET data in codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, search, max, min

I have a form that after submission my controller gets data from that form and sends  to model to retrieve a result from database based on the `_GET` information.

In my form there are two fields called min-year and max-year that i use them to search in year column in the database between those numbers.
The _GET array is like `'min-year'=>'something'` and `'max-year'=>'something'` after submission.

The _GET array is like 'min-year'=>'something' and 'max-year'=>'something' after submission.

Html:

```
<input type='text' name='state' />
<input type='text' name='min-year' />
<input type='text' name='max-year' />
```

controller:

```
$this->load->model('carinfo_model');
$where=($this->input->get());
$data['cars']=$this->carinfo_model->all_ad($where);
```

model:

```
public function all_ad($where){
->select("*")
->from("cars")
->where($where)         
$result=$this->db->get()->result_array();
return $result;
}
```

What is the fastest way to transform the `_GET` array into something readable for `'->where()'` to search in all other columns plus between min/max in year column in database?

I need a proper way to create a **'where'** statement(string or array), that contains **all other input fields plus a 'between' statement**, all in one query from $_GET information if it's possible

**If min-year,max-year or both of them or any other fields were submitted by empty value, result should be base on other fields and should still be able to get the result from database**

Please note i have so many other input fields and this is just part of the form.

Comment: show us your code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In View**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>Controller/Method/MinYear/MaxYead"></a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>welome/diff/2013/2016"></a>
```

**In Controller**

```
public function diff($min, $max) # Informing method there can be 2 input parameter from URL.
{
    $now = date("Y");
    $minYear = date_format('Y-m-d', $min.'-01-01');
    $maxYear = ($now == $max) ? date("Y-m-d") :  date_format('Y-m-d', $max.'-12-31');

    # in $maxYear if year is current year we cant take 2016-12-31. So we use Current timestamp.
    # If its not current year then we use 12-31. Ex 2014-12-31

}
```

> **Note:** I have not tested this code with your purpose. Sometimes if date not worked in `$minyear` use with `date()`
>   function like this
>   `$minYear = date(date_format('Y-m-d', $min.'-01-01'));`

---

**EDIT 01**

```
public function diff()
{
    $min = $this->input->get('min-year');
    $max = $this->input->get('max-year');
    $state = $this->input->get('state');  # updated

    $now = date("Y");
    $minYear = date_format('Y-m-d', $min.'-01-01');
    $maxYear = ($now == $max) ? date("Y-m-d") :  date_format('Y-m-d', $max.'-12-31');

    $data['cars'] = $this->carinfo_model->all_ad($minYear, $maxYear, $state);  # updated
}
```

**In Model**

```
public function all_ad($minYear, $maxYear, $state)  # updated
{
    $this->db->select(*);
    $this->db->from('cars');
    $this->db->where('field_name BETWEEN date($minYear) AND date($maxYear)');
    $this->db->where('field_name', $state ); # updated
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But my input is just a number like 1982 and is not in date format so i just need a way to transform that array into something to search between to numbers

Comment: `$min` and `$max` is just an 4 value number. It means its just an year. So with that i have give you rest of code. All you have to do is add that date with Mysql `Between` function and can retrieve your all data.

Comment: Seems close to what i need but what about the other inputs? I have added another input to html form. please check it out and see how to handle the other input fields which are not in between condition, in ->where statement?

Comment: U can pass state as other inputs in query @webarch... Anyway once again good one CI GURU abdulla

Comment: The thing is i want to retrieve result based on other fields if no min-year and max-year is submitted so where statement shouldn't be dependent to any certain field.

Comment: If there ia no field how you get min and max year? Its not possible

Comment: @WebArch happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.It's a controller function code. Paste this in your controller function and change the field name like your database table field name.

```
    $a = $this->input->get();
    $state = $a['state'];
    $min_yr = $a['min-year'];
    $max_yr = $a['max-year'];

    $where = "(field_name BETWEEN '$min_yr' AND '$max_yr') AND state = '$state'";
```

Send the where clause in your model function.

Comment: What if form submitted by empty min-year or max-year ? In my case the where clause should still return the result based on other input fields.Do you also mean if i have some other inputs, i have to put them in some variables one by one and send to where statement as you said?

Comment: Create your where clause inside `if(condition)`. Check the variable is null or not. You can add other inputs one by one followed by `AND`

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like below.

In controller get both value in different variable as given below:

```
$min_year = $this->input->get('min_year');
$max_year = $this->input->get('max_year');
```

then pass this variable into your model function like below:

$this->model_name->function_name($min_year,$max_year);

In model use between query as given below:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE year BETWEEN $min_year AND $max_year";
$result = $this->db->query($sql)->get()->result_array();
```

In $result you will get your result.

Comment: Your code is alright but you haven't mentioned other inputs in where clause. I need the best way to do this query using all of inputs in the form not just min and max

Comment: you just add your condition before BETWEEN.

Comment: for example some think like this $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE $i < $j AND year BETWEEN $min_year AND $max_year";

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your solution is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It's a controller function code. Paste this in your controller function and change the field name like your database table field name.

```
  $a = $this->input->get();
    $state = $a['state'];
    $min_yr = $a['min-year'];
    $max_yr = $a['max-year'];

    $where = "(field_name BETWEEN '$min_yr' AND '$max_yr') AND state = '$state'";
```

Send the where clause in your model function.